# Changing YYYY-MM-DD to three different columns

Tags: r, datetime

I am struggling to find information on changing a singe date into three columns.

Current Data:

```
      Date
2018-06-07
2017-03-01
2015-11-30
```

Desired Result

```
Year  Month  Day
2018     06   07
2017     03   01
2015     11   30
```

Comment: What is the actual format of your date values? Are they `character` objects with the year/month/day values split with a consistent character (as above) or are they `POSIXct` or another date format?

Comment: If they're just 'character' objects, look at the `separate` function in the `dplyr` package

Comment: h <- g %>% separate(date,  c( "Year","Month", "Day")) Thank you!!! This code worked perfect

Answer (score 3):

**1) chron** Since the input was not specified reproducibly we assume this:

```
Dates <- c("2018-06-07", "2017-03-01", "2015-11-30")
```

in which case this would work -- you can omit the `[...]` part if column order does not matter:

```
library(chron)
do.call("cbind", month.day.year(Dates)[c("year", "month", "day")])
```

giving this matrix (use `data.frame` in place of `cbind` if you want a data frame):

```
     year month day
[1,] 2018     6   7
[2,] 2017     3   1
[3,] 2015    11  30
```

The above code will also work if Dates is of `"Date"` class.

**2) format (base)**

```
DatestoNum <- function(fmt) as.numeric(format(as.Date(Dates), fmt))
sapply(c(year = "%Y", month = "%m", day = "%d"), DatestoNum)
```

giving the same result.  This will also work if `Dates` is of `"Date"` class. In that case you can optionally remove the `as.Date`.  Use `as.data.frame` on the result if you prefer a data frame result.

**2a)** Alternately write it out:

```
cbind(year = DatestoNum("%Y"), month = DatestoNum("%m"), day = DatestoNum("%d"))
```

**3) lubridate**

```
library(lubridate)

cbind(year = year(Dates), month = month(Dates), day = day(Dates))
```

**4) read.table (base)**

```
read.table(text = format(Dates), sep = "-", col.names = c("year", "month", "day"))
```

If `Dates` is already character you could optionally omit `format`.

Comment: Very nice. For completeness, `data.table` works from the textual string as follows.  Given `library(data.table)` and `d <- setDT(read.csv(text="<text as above>"))`, we can just do `d[, .(Year=year(Date), Month=month(Date), Day=mday(Date))]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dates <- c("2018-06-07", "2017-03-01", "2015-11-30")
> scan(text=Dates, what=list(Year="",Month="",Day=""), sep="-")
Read 3 records
$Year
[1] "2018" "2017" "2015"

$Month
[1] "06" "03" "11"

$Day
[1] "07" "01" "30"
```

So that's in a "dataframe" arrangement:

```
data.frame( scan(text=Dates, what=list(Year="",Month="",Day=""),
                 sep="-", quiet=TRUE) )
#-------
  Year Month Day
1 2018    06  07
2 2017    03  01
3 2015    11  30
```

If those values were already Date- (or factor-) classed variables in a dataframe or list, then you would need `as.character` to coerce the `Date` column for this to succeed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the user is just keeping the dates as strings which need to be split on a separator character. In this case, using `tidyr::separate` is the easiest solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
Dates <- data.frame(id = c('a', 'b', 'c'),
                    date = c("2018-06-07", "2017-03-01", "2015-11-30"))
Dates %>%
    separate(date, c("Year","Month","Day"))

  id Year Month Day
1  a 2018    06  07
2  b 2017    03  01
3  c 2015    11  30
```

The safer solution is probably to store the dates as some kind of date object. In that case you would want to use the solutions posted by @G.Grothendieck.